# Перемещение вершины полигона мышью (OpenGL)

Tags: c++, opengl, графика

Какой самый оптимальный способ реализовать перемещение вершины полигона мышкой?

Первое, что приходит в голову - сравнивать положение курсора с каждой точкой в массиве вершин (+ некоторое смещение по координатам, чтобы расширить область попадания в вершину).

Будет ли этот вариант оптимальным? Ведь каждый кадр необходимо будет пробежать по всему массиву, который может иметь очень большой размер (меш какой-либо фигуры, например).

Comment: то, что вам нужно, называется spatial query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В свое время я делал это так - первая отрисовка как обычно на экран, а потом ещё одна в отдельный буфер. Но не просто отрисовка, а особая. Все интересующие точки рисуются разными цветами и так, что бы соответствие цвет-номер(id) точки было однозначным. То, что не интересно, даже не рисуется. И теперь задача решается элементарно - по координатам получаем цвет, а цвет однозначно конвертируем в индекс массива или какой то внутренний id. В моем случае было легко - у меня была 2д картинка и я рисовал второе на обычной bitmap.

В случае OpenGl можно воспользоваться функцией glReadPixels, которая как раз позволяет прочитать пиксель по координатам.

То есть, в цикле отрисовки Вам нужно создать ещё один буфер, и там ещё раз нарисовать то же самое (с определенными упрощениями конечно) и готово. Этот буфер (и код отрисовки удобен тем, что можно нарисовать это прям по верху картинки и сравнить.

Также, не стоит забывать, что если на экране рисуем 4к картинку, то эта вспомогательная картинка может вполне быть в 16 раз меньше.

Информацию к размышлению можно почерпнуть в этом туториале - https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-Lighting/Bloom (да, там о блум-эффекте, но суть такая же).

Comment: Зачем цвета то, есть же GL_R32UI ну или GL_RG32UI чтоб прямо указатель запихнуть.

Comment: ох ох.  ну очевидно же что цвет выражается каким то числом. Но запихать указатель (который с вероятностью 99% у большинства программистов 64битный) в 32битное - плохая рекомендация. Очень плохая.

Comment: но в два 32 битных значения влезет.

Comment: Но в этом случае появляется много проблем. Начиная с отрисовки (у нас есть 64битный цвет) и объема памяти в пустую.

Comment: Это какие такие проблемы? И где память впустую уходит?

Comment: Если хочется сохранять указатель, то придется тратить два пикселя на один указатель (на 64битной системе). И тут либо нужно будет придумывать свою отрисовку (что совсем не улучшит ситуацию), либо рисовать первые 4 байта на одой картинке, а следующие на второй.

Comment: out ivec2 gFragColor; in ivec2 a_pointer;

Comment: что мне говорит, что либо Вы не совсем понимаете, о чем говорите, либо Ваше решение такое, что я его не понимаю. Если Вы можете сделать хорошее решение - кнопка ответа всегда доступна.